# systemverilog use array as port of module/function

Tags: system-verilog

```
module hh ( input [2:0] a [0:3], output b );

wire [2:0] c1 [4:1];
wire [0:2] c2 [0:3];
wire d;

u_hh_1 hh ( .a(c1          ), .b(d) ); // it is right;
u_hh_2 hh ( .a(c1[4:1][2:0]), .b(d) ); // illegal slice name;
u_hh_3 hh ( .a(c2          ), .b(d) ); // it is right,
                                       // and in the netlist,
                                       // the bits of c2 is swapped to a;
u_hh_4 hh ( .a(c2[0:3][2:0]), .b(d) ); // illegal slice name;
```

I know using an array in the port list is only supported in **systemverilog**, not verilog. In order to make this more readable, I want to display the range explicitly, but it is illegal. The same problem happens with functions.  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemVerilog syntax does not allow you to specify more than one range, that that range has to be the rightmost selected dimension.

If you want to be explicit, create a `typedef` and use a cast. Using a typedef is also a better programming practice instead of having arbitrary numbers scattered about your code.

```
typedef logic [2:0] blue_port_t[4:1];
typedef logic [0:2] green_port_t[0:3];

module hh ( input green_port_t a, output wire b );

wire blue_port_t c1;
wire green_port_t c2;
wire d;

u_hh_1 hh ( .a(c1          ), .b(d) ); // 
u_hh_2 hh ( .a(blue_port_t'(c1)), .b(d) ); //
u_hh_3 hh ( .a(c2          ), .b(d) ); // it is right,
                                       // and in the netlist,
                                       // the bits of c2 is swapped to a;
u_hh_4 hh ( .a(green_port_t'(c2)), .b(d) );
```

The cast does not do anything other than document the type in use.

Answer (score 0):

In Verilog you should try to make your vectors go from MS to LS preferable ending in 0. It is a convention which makes it easier for other Verilog coders to read it. 
The same convention: memories should go just the opposite way: LS to MS starting with zero. (But I have seen lots of code where this is not the case. Some simulators give a warning if you do that).

```
wire [2:0] c1 [0:3];
wire [2:0] c2 [0:3];
```

If you want your code to be synthesis-able you can use two-dimensional slices but the index is [memory_address][bit-slice] The bit-slice is optional. If its omitted you get the whole entry.
Thus you can do:

```
c1[1][1:0] // LS 2 bits of second entry of memory c1
c1[0]      // First memory entry of c1 which is 3 bits wide
```

You can never do:

```
c1[1:0]
```

Which is logical as it would select the first TWO entries of the memory at the same time which is not supported by any standard hardware.